# Batch array call by variable

Tags: arrays, variables, batch-file

i got a problem with my batch file that echo two array contents.

```
for /L %%i in (1,2,%n%) do (
    set /A next=%%i+1

    echo !array[%%i]!
    echo !array[%next%]!  //This doesn't work
)
```

Output:

```
_content_array
ECHO is off.
```

When i turn Echo on the Output is:

```
 _content_array
 ECHO is on.
```

_content_array is perfect, it works.
But the 2nd call (!array[%next%]!) doesn't work, i think i just failed to call, i tried out some other calls but it never worked for me.

Thx for your time.

Comment: How big is your array? Are you sure, there is an `!array[%next%]!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /L %%i in (1,2,%n%) do (
    set /A next=%%i+1

    echo !array[%%i]!
    for %%n in (!next!) do echo !array[%%n]!
)
```

You may read full details about this solution at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).